# jasmine-expect cannot find jest, jasmine v2.x, or jasmine v1.x

Tags: javascript, jasmine, redux, jasmine2.0

I'm trying **unit test** with [jasmine-expect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-expect). However I keep getting the error:

> jasmine-expect cannot find jest, jasmine v2.x, or jasmine v1.x

I have installed the latest version of jasmine. What am I missing?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Person.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "add-matchers": "^0.4.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.3",
    "jasmine-expect": "^3.6.0",
    "jest": "^18.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "deep-freeze": "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

**My Code:**

```
'use strict';
import expect from 'jasmine-expect';

console.log('It is working...');
```

**Error Message:** 
[image]

Comment: @therewillbecode thanks for the quick response. I have installed the latest version of jest but still get the same error. I have updated my package.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to the [mjackson expect](https://github.com/mjackson/expect) library. It seems to be working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers/tree/master/examples/jest for a working example of jasmine-expect with jest, thanks.